# Show background-color on full width of child element of horizontally scrolling element

Tags: html, css

In a horizontally scrolling div, when I move the horizontal scrollbar, the `background-color` of `.filesColumn:focus` does not show completely (for the complete width).

(If i add `overflow-x:auto` into `.fileColumn`, it shows full width).

What can I do to show the `background-color` on the child element completely when I move the horizontal scrollbar of the containing `div.contentModel`?

Please see code : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VincentHsieh/t0Lswzso/)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgba(16, 40, 136, 1);
}

.contentModal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.filesColumn {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(16, 40, 136, 1);
}

.filesColumn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(48, 88, 184, 1);
}

.filesColumn:active,
.filesColumn:focus {
  background-color: rgba(79, 134, 235, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="contentModal">
        <a href="#" class="filesColumn">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</a>
        <a href="#" class="filesColumn">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</a>
        <a href="#" class="filesColumn">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant codes in here too.

Comment: @Vincent Hsieh - you can add basic code snippets like jsfidde by clicking `<>` icon when asking your question.

Comment: The problem is the `display:block` with the `<a>`, can you use divs or paragraphs instead ?

Comment: @DomeTune That doesn't seem to fix it. `display: inline` would fix it, but you don't get the ability to add the padding shown in the code.

Comment: @DanEastwell Thats why i asked for `<div>` and `<p>`. You should not apply any `display`.

Comment: @DomeTune Well, nice work, seems to fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `.filesColumn` `display: inline-block` and remove `width: 100%`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgba(16, 40, 136, 1);
}

.contentModal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.filesColumn {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(16, 40, 136, 1);
}

.filesColumn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(48, 88, 184, 1);
}

.filesColumn:active,
.filesColumn:focus {
  background-color: rgba(79, 134, 235, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="contentModal">
        <a href="#" class="filesColumn">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</a>
        <a href="#" class="filesColumn">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</a>
        <a href="#" class="filesColumn">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't solve it. Behaves exactly like in the question. Latest FF beta on windows, if that matters. P.S. Maybe because your snippet says .filesColumn display:block instead of what you suggested :)

Comment: @MatveyAndreyev Approved the edit. Sorry, that was my silly copy paste error :)

Comment: @DanEastwell I have tried this way before.but I want the `.filesColumn` `background-color` to be filled the width of `.contentModal`.

Answer (score 0):

It does, this seemes to be a bug with JSfiddle. Look here on codepen for a working example. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZebBB

```
    html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgba(16, 40, 136, 1);
}

.contentModal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.filesColumn {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(16, 40, 136, 1);
}

.filesColumn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(48, 88, 184, 1);
}

.filesColumn:active,
.filesColumn:focus {
  background-color: rgba(79, 134, 235, 1);
}
```

Comment: You can replicate the bug/issue in the code snippet (i.e. SO's code editor) above, too.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is your solution :-)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgba(16, 40, 136, 1);
}

.contentModal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.filesColumn {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-color: rgba(16, 40, 136, 1);
}

.filesColumn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(48, 88, 184, 1);
}

.filesColumn:active,
.filesColumn:focus {
  background-color: rgba(79, 134, 235, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="contentModal">
        <a class="filesColumn">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</a>
        <a class="filesColumn">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</a>
        <a class="filesColumn">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</a>
    </div>
</div>
```